# How to use Cloudinary backend SDK on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

We're implementing an upload of large files to Cloudinary. To avoid routing the data through our backend I'd like to upload directly to Cloudinary using unsigned upload[1] in the browser.

Since I need to support files larger than 100 MB I also need to use the chunked method for larger files.

The frontend is a React app. I went through all the Cloudinary frontend SDKs but I can't find exactly what I need.

- The "upload widget" doesn't fit in our design.
- We don't use JQuery so we can't (and don't want to) use the Jquery Cloudinary plugin.

We just want to call the APIs directly hence we'd like to use Backend Node SDK and its `upload_stream` and `upload_large_stream` methods which do the heavy lifting of chunking the file. Unfortunately, this SDK relies on Node APIs and can't be used in browsers.

What else are our options here?

---

[1] or possibly fetching the request signature from a specially prepared backend endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to upload to Cloudinary directly from the client side without using the Cloudinary [Upload Widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) or [jQuery SDK](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration) - instead, just plain JavaScript that you can then include in your React app. Those client side uploads can also be chunked.

There is an example implementation in the Cloudinary Documentation at the following section - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#code_explorer_chunked_asset_upload_from_the_client_side

That example uses an [Unsigned upload](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#unsigned_upload) with just the `file` and `upload_preset` (as required parameters) + any [unsigned upload parameters](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#unsigned_upload_parameters) - though you can also use Signed uploads by modifying the code in that example to make a request to your Backend server to sign the relevant upload parameters you will pass in the upload request and receive back the signature which you would pass in your upload request to Cloudinary.

You could find out more details and examples on how you can manually (without any SDKs) generate an authentication signature on your server from the following section of the Documentation - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures - you can then use that signature as part of your uploads - if you want to use Signed uploads instead of Unsigned.

Both unsigned and signed approaches support uploading the asset from the client side to Cloudinary directly without needing to send the file to your server or to use any SDKs.